# Entity Framework "source" table approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I think it's a trivial problem but wanted to ask you about clean solution for it.

This time I have a table `Cards` in my database already filled with a couple thousand rows. I want to treat this table as read-only source of data with all possible items that user can store in his collection.

When I create migration for this models, it keeps adding a `CollectionsId` column to the `Cards` table, which I totally understand but this is something that I would like to avoid.

My question is: should I create additional class for cards like `UserCard` and use it for storing in collection? If so then it creates a problem because it's forcing me to validate `UserCard` with `Card` if its valid or not. Should it be stored in separate context? What's is the best approach for this kind of problem?

```
abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Card : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Set { get; set; }
}

class User : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
}

class Collection : Entity
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set ;}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but you should really not be using a base Entity class.  It doesn't gain you anything and needlessly complicates the model.

Comment: Why is that? I've seen it in many solutions, it seems to be handy with generic classess or interfaces.

Comment: Base Entity has nothing to do with this issue, and is a REALLY good OO practice, especially here, you are declaring that all your entities will have an integer Id field. Happy coding, this design choice will simplify your journey down the track.

Comment: `class Collection` confused me. is it the `bridge-table` to make `many-to-many` relationship between `User` and `Card`? how many table are there in your database? can you list your tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have defined that Collection contains many cards, the default implementation that EF injects on your behalf is to include a *Foreign Key* column into the `Collection` table to track which `Collection` the `Card` belongs to.

> The additional fields that are injected as part of the EF migration are called ***[Shadow Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties)*** these properties are part of the model, and necessary components to ensure your model functions the way you have declared it, but these properties are not defined in your class structure (meaning you cannot use them in queries or code)
>
> > ***[Shadow Foreign Key Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api#no-foreign-key-property)*** Are the specific type of fields that are being injected in OPs model.

One way around this is to change the definition of `Collection` to Have a single Card reference, instead of having a colleciton of cards, this design choice will require you to have an additional column that could allow you to keep track of the 'name' of the collection (or another Id that you would manage in the app)

- this will work in terms of data schema, but will be less intuitive to query and work with, because now the *concept* of a *Collection* has become more abstract. For smaller projects like this it really helps to keep the database tables and concepts in line with your business domain.

Another way around this is to create a linking table between Collection and Card, which itself is not a bad design, `Card` really becomes a *Card Definition* (often referred to as **Card** *Type*) and you can create a new table called `CollectionCard` that specifies the card that has been added to the collection.

The next implementation change you can make it is to remove the *element of surprise* that EF has when it introduces *Shadow Properties* to support your class structure in the database and fully define the pointing fields that are required, then you can easily use attribute notation to declare the specific fields to use to record foreign key links.

```
abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>Definition of all 'available' types of card</summary>
/// <remarks>It might make sense to refer or rename this table to CardType</remarks>
class Card : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Set { get; set; }
}

class User : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Collection> Collections { get; set; } = new HashSet<Collection>();
}

class Collection : Entity
{
    public int UserId { get;set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CollectionCard> Cards { get; set; } = new HashSet<CollectionCard>();
}

class CollectionCard : Entity
{
    public int CollectionId { get;set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CollectionId))]
    public virtual Collection Collection { get; set; }

    public int CardId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CardId))]
    public virtual Card Card { get; set; }
}
```

This structure is useful in card game type of scenarios because you can easily import/export the card definitions list without causing too much adverse problems with the rest of the dataset.

> Notice that I have added value to your `Entity` base class by decorating the `Id` field with the `KeyAttribute`. While EF works well from a `Convention-Only` approach, I recommend a hybrid between using attribute notation especially for all *Foreign* and *Primary* key configuration, and allowing model conventions to manage less important structural defintions.
>
> > Reserve fluent model notations to scenarios where the attribute notation is not viable or the conventions are not working for you. 
> >     - this advise is based on the reality that it is hard to find/maintain fluent notations down the track as your model grows, attirbute notation is contained with each field, which is the primary reference point when you don't know what a field does in your model.